# Field Collection Value field is not deleting correctly(using programmatically)

Tags: 7, entities

I installed the [Field ollection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module in a Drupal 7 site and I added a multi-field (unlimited) field collection with three items.

I need to programmatically delete the field collection.

I used the following code, which does not work.

```php
$field_collection_delete = $node->field_accommodation['und'][$j]['value']; 
entity_delete_multiple('field_collection_item', array($field_collection_delete));
```

The value in the field collection item is deleted from the database, but the field collection field I added in the content type is still in the database.

I need to delete that too.

> [image: screenshot]

What code do I need to use to make it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unset the field from node first!

```
unset($node->field_accommodation['und'][$j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should delete field collections by calling `$field_collection->delete();` This handles a few other things for you such as deleting the parent entity.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, I tried the $field_collection->delete(); but its work same like the entity_delete_multiple(). Only deleting the field collection item from the field collection and not the field collection value  from the content type