# Field Collection Data Deletion for particular Content type

Tags: entities

I have one senario where 2 for content type i have added field collection field.

Each content type has around 3k plus nodes data. each nodes has 50+ records of field collections. All content creation done through excel import functionality.

For second content type, the field collection records that i imported is wrong. i want delete all the fields collection items only for second content type.

How to do it? i can't manually since it has 3k+ nodes and 50+ records in each nodes.

Any module which handle these kind of scenario? or any coding documentation which help me here.

as i search i got few related links as below. but none of them completely fit my requirement.

Could anyone please let me know or help me achieve this.

[Deleting field collection items](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161024/deleting-field-collection-items) : As mentioned on this page i can't play with DB.

[Field Collection Value field is not deleting correctly(using programmatically)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98687/field-collection-value-field-is-not-deleting-correctlyusing-programmatically) : looks like i can use it deletion of data. but how for particular content type.

And I have to give one interface on the site where a non-technical guy can handle this if the same mistake happens.

If anybody knows please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to do this using code. IF your using D7, try following code in any custom module or in a basic page.

```
//Use a query to get all nodes of your particular content type.

$results = db_query("SELECT nid FROM node WHERE type = 'your-content-type'");
$nids = array();
foreach($results as $result){
  $nids[] = $result->nid;
}

foreach($nids as $nid){ // use for loop for testing
  $node = node_load($nid);
  foreach ($node->field_international_activity[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $key => $value) {
   // Build array of field collection values.
   $field_collection_item_values[] = $value['value'];

   // Unset them.  
   unset($node->field_international_activity[LANGUAGE_NONE][$key]);
  }

// Delete field collection items.
entity_delete_multiple('field_collection_item', $field_collection_item_values);
node_save($node);
}
```

For more details please refer [link1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68765/how-to-properly-delete-a-field-collection), [link2](https://www.drupal.org/node/2684165)

This code is not tested, first just try for a single node by using a **for loop** instead of **foreach**.

Comment: Instead of querying the database for the nids, and loading the nodes. `node_load_multiple` can be used. Something like  `$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => 'your_content_type', 'status' => 1));` which would reduce the first for loop and improve the performance though it's a one time process.

Comment: you are right @SureshR. I missed that.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Abin and Suresh R for saving my time... it worked..